# Problems in creating volume in mapr hadoop

Tags: hadoop, volume, mapr

I want to create a volume(MyVolume) but it can not mount the volume. it says this error: Failed to mount volume MyVolume, Permission denied its permission is root and admin.how can i create volume that comes to folder my cluster? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the user you are logging in as doesn't have the right permissions.  This link will help you set the permissions up correctly:

http://www.mapr.com/doc/display/MapR/Managing+Permissions

When starting a new cluster, I typically create a 'mapr' user and give him admin permissions with this command:

maprcli acl edit -type cluster -user mapr:fc

Hope this helps!